# binary search only using length?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary

So I wrote a binary search function that takes an array of integers, a low index search value, a high index search value, and a check value:

```
int binarySearch(int d[], int low, int high, int check)  
{
int mid = (high-low)/2 + low;

if(low > high)
    return -1;

if(d[mid] == check)
    return mid;
else if(check > d[mid])
    return binarySearch(d, mid+1, high, check);
else
    return binarySearch(d, low, mid-1, check);
}
```

However, I was asked to write a binary search function accepting only the array of data, the length of the array, and a search value? How could I do this without having low and high variables? How could I declare low and high variables in terms of size?

```
int binSearch(int d[], int size, int check)
```

Comment: Convert the (tail-)recursive function to a non-recursive loop. `low` can then be a local variable with the initial value 0. Or write a wrapper function to `binarySearch`.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to depend on the language.

In C, it is possible by changing the pointer to the head of the array, instead to consider the full array, consider only the 2nd half of it.

```
if in 1st half:
    arr = arr // unchanged
    size = size/2 //only the size and thus end point change
if in 2nd half:
    arr = arr + size/2  //only the 2nd half is considered
    size = size/2 //and size is also changing
```

When returning from recursive call, you of course need to add the gap you added in the 2nd case to the answer.

In java, you cannot really do it efficiently (assuming you still want a recursive binary search), since an array is an object that you cannot (nicely) just mutate the starting point of. You can of course create a copy of the relevant subarray - but that's going to lose the point of binary search being efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the function as a loop, where recursion is replaced with another pass through the loop with other variable values. The loop variables can be local variables and don't have to be exposed in the interface. In your recursive calls to the binary search function, you have to adjust only one of the parameters, either `low`or `high`, which makes rewriting the function easy:

```
int binarySearch(int d[], int length, int check)  
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = length;

    while (low < high) {
        int mid = (high - low) / 2 + low;

        if (d[mid] == check) return mid;

        if (check > d[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Note that I've used a slightly different way to describe the currently searched sub-array: `low` is the inclusive lower bound, but the upper bound `high` is exclusive. This is the natural representation of ranges in languages that use zero-based array indexing. An empty sub-array is then repesented by `low == high`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple - in fact, you are almost done: all you need is a one-line wrapper around your recursive function that transforms the four-argument function into three-argument function.

Write the function that matches the desired signature:

```
int binSearch(int d[], int size, int check) {
    return binarySearch(d, 0, size-1, check);
}
```

Of course you can get fancy with pointers, too: instead of passing `low` as a separate parameter, you can pass `&d[low]` as the new `d`, and `high-low` for the length.

Comment: I don't think that is what the interviewer meant when asking for a different signature, but could be wrong. The lack of visibility modifier in the function signature suggests c.

Comment: @amit The fact that he's writing `int d[]` instead of `int[] d` suggests it's probably not Java :-) I'm not sure it's an interview question, either - it could very well be a school assignment.

Comment: And convention of `foo() <newline> {` in OP (disgusting, I know!)